# Determining which column is visible to the right of a frozen pane in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'd like to determine in VBA which column is shown directly to the right of a frozen pane, in the example image, it would be column `G`.

See the picture for reference.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The home key moves your active selection to the leftmost available cell in the non-frozen part of your worksheet, so if you simulate a home key button press and then fetch a location, you could have your answer. It's not a very clean solution though.

Answer (score 0):

This will work -

```
Sub test()

With ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
Dim frzcol As Integer
Dim frzleft As Range
Dim toprow As Integer

toprow = .Row
frzcol = .Column
Set frzleft = Cells(toprow, frzcol)
MsgBox (frzleft.Address)



End With
End Sub
```

Change the `msgbox` to whatever it is you want to do. Use the range to get the column.

Note it will only work if there is **at least** one *hidden* column. You could use an `if` to check to see if there are any hidden and if not, just hard code it.